# Are there any naming conventions for self-referential, many-to-many relationship tables?

Tags: sql, relational-database, naming-conventions, naming

Let's say we have a table called `Users` for a fictional social media platform. In addition to regular users, some more experienced users are asked to be "greeters" where they are assigned other, newer users to greet and encourage. Because greeters aren't always available, multiple greeters are assigned to each new user and each greeter is assigned multiple new users.

Thus we have a self-referential, many-to-many user relationship we need a link table for.

**Are there any conventions for this case?**

Here are some ideas based on conventions I've found for standard many-to-many tables:

- `user_user`: doesn't tell us much and there might be more than one relationship like this
- `Greeters`: (i.e. use a new name that describes the relationship) pretty good, but it doesn't communicate that it's a link table or related to `Users`
- `greeter_user`: (use a different name for one part of the relationship)

What do you use or what would you recommend?

Comment: not reeally, you have to think in 3 or 4 years and you want to understand your design, so greeter_user or user_user with greeter_id, user:_id as columns would suffice to understand, what for the bridge table is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the entity–relationship model this would be modeled as *user encourages user*.

[image: ER diagram where M users encourages N users]

This could be translated into the tables *Users* and *Encouragements*.

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
   username VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY,
   ...
);

CREATE TABLE Encouragements (
   greeterName VARCHAR(32),
   newbieName VARCHAR(32),
   PRIMARY KEY (greeterName, newbieName),
   FOREIGN KEY (greeterName) REFERENCES Users(username),
   FOREIGN KEY (newbieName) REFERENCES Users(username)
);
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model

Comment: I like how you've named the link table for the relationship itself rather than the names of participants in the relationship. (Like Friendship instead of Friend) That seems to clearly show it's not a standard table and also help explain what it does.